# Is there a way I can share files or stream from a PC on a 5ghz band to 2.4ghz?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, streaming

I have a D-Link DWR-953 router. Whenever I am using steam in game stream or browsing files on my PC with file explorer It stops finding my PC Once my laptop switches to 2.4GHz, The same happens with Steam streaming, It just suddenly freezes and quits. Is there a way I can fix this? my PC is close to the router and can use 5GHz, but whenever my Laptop is near the TV it can only connect with 2.4GHz.

Comment: You don’t indicate what OS you are using.

Comment: @Ramhound wifi is wifi. It behaves the same on any OS, so its not really an issue.

Comment: @LPChip the OS tells you what debugging tools they have to work with, it's pertinent.

Comment: @pbhj good point.

Comment: @LPChip - I don't normally explain the reason I want certain information. 
 However, in order for uou understand the reason, file sharing is handled per network in Windows, but that behavior might differ in other operating systems.  The 2.4 GHz network the author's system knows about is different then 5.0 GHz and could in theory not have the same file sharing configuration.  The author is not clear if the computer is rediscovered after an initial period. *I shouldn't have to explain the reason information is important, so I don't normally do it, but I made an exception in this case*

Comment: I would like to add that there is an alternative solution.  Some routers have the capability of treating multiple bands as a single network.  This would allow the router to handle the transition itself and all the OS would know is they are connected to it.  This of course requires a dual-band network adapter to be possible in addition to a router that offers this option.  This might or might not require the use of the software that comes with that adapter.  The feature I describe is also a premiere feature which means it normally is on routers that are typically more expensive.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows, I figured it doesn't matter but apparently it does. my Phone find my PC using FING

Comment: I have no idea what FING is, if it is what I think it is (a network tool), then what I described isn't offered by it.  Windows WILL NOT automatically switch networks even if they have the same SSID seamlessly.  That must be handled by the access point not the client device

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior.

When you switch between 5Ghz and 2.4Ghz, you loose network connection. Any program that has still connections open is waiting for the previous connection to come back unless it times out, which is usually 30 seconds. Only after the time-out, will it reinitialize the connection using whatever means available, or it will simply disconnect you.

How can you solve your problem? Well the answer is obvious, but make sure the connection does not switch. One of the reasons it will switch is because the 5Ghz got out of reach. Yes, even if the 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz are from the same device, a 2.4Ghz is slower but has a higher range than a 5Ghz has.

To combat this, either forget the 5Ghz connection and stick with the 2.4 Ghz one, or place a wifi extender to extend the range of the 5Ghz. An accesspoint can also be used, but this can still cause for the above to happen because switching from one point on the 5Ghz to the other point on 5Ghz is still a switch in most cases. (It requires specific hardware for both the router and the accesspoint to carry the transmission seamlessly from one point to another.

Alternatively, move the router so the coverage changes.

Comment: If I connect to 2.4GHz my PC will not even find the my laptop or vice versa

Comment: It should, unless you have configured one of the two to be a guest or different vlan.

Comment: uhmm Nope I just changed both SSIDs of the bands to the same and changed the password :c

Comment: Changing the name and password and bands don't matter. Making one of the bands a Guest is a setting inside the router.

Comment: I couln't find an option like that anywhere